# Packaging system in Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

I would like to use the R6RS library/module system as detailed in Dybvig's [TSPL4 chapter 10](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/libraries.html#./libraries:h0) in Racket. I selected "Pretty Big" language in DrRacket. But when I do

```
(import (list-tools setops) (more-setops) (rnrs))
```

on the top window and run, I get this error:

"*import: misuse of unit keyword in: (import (list-tools setops) (more-setops) (rnrs))*"

How do I write and run r6rs programs and particularly use the packaging/module system as described by [R6RS Standard Section 7](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-10.html#node_chap_7) in Racket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Pretty Big" language is a legacy language (and it's marked as such in the language selection box).  You should not use it for the R6RS language.  To interact with R6RS code, you should use the top item in the language dialog ("Use the language declared in the source"), and start your programs with `#!r6rs`.  For more details, it's best to ask questions on the [Racket mailing list](http://racket-lang.org/community.html).